# How Can I Hide or Show Asp:Content using a Session in If statement

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, session

At my Production.aspx Web Form I have this code:

```
    <%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Index.Master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Production.aspx.cs" Inherits="WebPortal.Production" %>
    <asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="server">  
        <h3>PRODUCTION SITE</h3>    
        <img src="" alt="Production Logo" height="350" width="350" />
    </asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder2" runat="server">
    <asp:Login ID="Login1" runat="server" BackColor="#F7F7DE" BorderColor="#CCCC99" BorderStyle="Solid" BorderWidth="1px" Font-Names="Verdana" Font-Size="10pt" Height="187px" Width="235px">
        <TitleTextStyle BackColor="#6B696B" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="#FFFFFF" />
    </asp:Login>
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="Content3" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder3" runat="server">
</asp:Content>
```

And at my Production.aspx.cs Web Form i Have this Code:

```
namespace WebPortal
{
    public partial class Production : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                var GetSession = Session["Counter"];
                if (Convert.ToInt32(GetSession) == 1)
                {
                    // Show Content 1
                }
                else if (Convert.ToInt32(GetSession) == 2)
                {
                    // Show Content 2
                }
                else
                {
                    // Show Content 3
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex) 
            {
                // MessageBox.show(ex.message.tostring());
            }
        }     
    }
}
```

how can i try to hide a content based on the session value like when a user try to login by its account and based on its access level he gets a 1 which trigger the if statement then based on its value on what content to show..

Comment: IMHO you need to walk through Master Pages for different roles.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put **div** into every **content** and show/hide  div like folowing:

ASPX:

```
 <asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="server">  
 <div runat="server" id="div1">
    <h3>PRODUCTION SITE</h3>    
    <img src="" alt="Production Logo" height="350" width="350" />
    </div>
 </asp:Content>

 <asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder2" runat="server">
 <div runat="server" id="div2">
 <asp:Login ID="Login1" runat="server" BackColor="#F7F7DE" BorderColor="#CCCC99" BorderStyle="Solid" BorderWidth="1px" Font-Names="Verdana" Font-Size="10pt" Height="187px" Width="235px">
    <TitleTextStyle BackColor="#6B696B" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="#FFFFFF" />
   </asp:Login>
  </div>
  </asp:Content>
  <asp:Content ID="Content3" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder3" runat="server">
  <div runat="server" id="div3">
  <p>q3</p>
   </div>
   </asp:Content>
```

Code behind:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    div1.Visible = div2.Visible = div3.Visible = false;
    if (Session["Counter"] != null)
    {
        int GetSession = (int)Session["Counter"];
        if (GetSession == 1)
            div1.Visible = true;
        else if (GetSession == 2)
            div2.Visible = true;
        else
            div3.Visible = true;
    }
    else
        div3.Visible = true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're probably best using different nested master pages for different access levels as suggested above, though if you're stuck with what you've got you could use a multiview control on the master with three views, each holding one of the placeholders.

Add a MasterType directive to your content pages so you can reference the Master page then set the Multiview active index as required.

Code is not tested, just a rough idea -  I'd use a switch block instead of 'if' myself.

```
       protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {    
MultiView mv = (MultiView)Master.FindControl("multiView1");
                var GetSession = Session["Counter"];
                if (Convert.ToInt32(GetSession) == 1)
                {
                    mv.ActiveViewIndex = 0
                }
                else if (Convert.ToInt32(GetSession) == 2)
                {
                    mv.ActiveViewIndex = 1
                }
                else
                {
                    mv.ActiveViewIndex = 2
                }
            }
```